# Stdout & stderr not redirecting on autostart

Tags: bash, debian, stdout, stderr, autostart

I am using Raspbian (Debian with LXDE on a Raspberry Pi).

I have created the following two files. The first one is a .desktop file so as lxde can autostart my script, and the second one is the script in question.

The problem is that when I manually start the script it works perfect, creating the directories and redirecting the streams. However when I reboot the pi, and the script autostarts I get no output at all. The script is surelly working as my final app indeed starts. Only the streams are not there.

I have no idea for what to search for, or what causes this...

.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry] 

Type=Application

Exec=system_start.sh
```

system_start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/application.linux64/

mkdir system_log
DIR=system_log/$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir $DIR/
./start.sh 1> $DIR/$(date +%T)operation_log.txt 2> $DIR/$(date +%T)errors_log.txt
```

Comment: Same problem here, still haven't solved it :/

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with Linux Mint. A working command with redirect to a file did not work when started at boot using autostart .desktop file.

Enclosing the command in bash -c " " helped:

```
bash -c "/home/huehuehue/myguiapp >> /home/huehuehue/myguiapp.log 2>&1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the whole path instead of a relative path to make your script work in any circumstances and avoid `~`:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=/home/username/application.linux64/

mkdir $DIR/system_log
SUBDIR=system_log/$(date +%Y%m%d)
mkdir $SUBDIR
./start.sh 1> $SUBDIR/$(date +%T)operation_log.txt 2> $SUBDIR/$(date +%T)errors_log.txt
```

Comment: Sorry not to mention that, but I tried it too. I tried everything regarding the path, and every time the result was the same.